# How to create transparent/in-line/bridging firewall via nftables?

Tags: firewall, centos7, bridge, nftables

I'm stuck at configuring nftables.

```
table bridge filter {
    chain input { type filter hook input priority -200; policy accept;}
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority -200; policy drop;
        ip protocol icmp counter accept;
    }
    chain output { type filter hook output priority 200; policy accept;}
```

I have a couple of questions.
Rule `ip protocol icmp counter accept;` does not work. Counter showing +1 packet in minute or so and ping not working.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have first to allow ARP resolution to work. Local IP resolution relies on ARP:

```
nft add rule bridge filter forward ether type arp accept
```

Else when trying to ping, arp resolution fails and you get something like this on a node trying to cross the bridge:

```
# ip neigh show eth0
192.168.1.7 dev eth0  FAILED
```